# composer / satis svn repository http basic authentication

Tags: authentication, svn, satis, mod-dav-svn

I am trying to create a composer package repository for my company using satis.
My svn repositories are acessed via http (apache svn).

I am trying to add this to my config.json of satis

```
{
    "name": "packages",
    "homepage": "http://packages.example.org",
    "repositories": [
        { "type": "svn",
          "url": "myrepourl" 
       }

    ],
    "require-all": true
}
```

THe problem is that I cant authenticate in the repository:

```
Repository could  not be processed, svn: OPTIONS of  authorization failed. basic authentication rejected.
```

How can I pass the username/password to satis?.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to [composer documentation](http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md#security), you have to put your user key files or your certificate in your project, not in the satis configuration :

Using SSH :

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "ssh2.sftp://example.org",
            "options": {
                "ssh2": {
                    "username": "composer",
                    "pubkey_file": "/home/composer/.ssh/id_rsa.pub",
                    "privkey_file": "/home/composer/.ssh/id_rsa"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Using Certificate :

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://example.org",
            "options": {
                "ssl": {
                    "cert_file": "/home/composer/.ssl/composer.pem",
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```